# Googleapiclient creating a group

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-groups-api

I have the following routine

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

self.service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)

def create_alias(self,oktalogin,personal):
    groupInfo = {}

    #groupInfo["adminCreated"]= True
    groupInfo["kind"]= "admin#directory#group"
    groupInfo["email"]= oktalogin
    groupInfo["name"]="Security Alias"
    groupInfo["description"]="Security Alias"
        
    print(json.dumps(groupInfo))
    response = self.service.groups().insert(body=json.dumps(groupInfo)).execute()
```

My understanding is this creates the following object for use against the API

```
 {"kind": "admin#directory#group", "email": "source@source.com", "name": "Security Alias", "description": "Security Alias"}
```

The API replies with the following .

```
 raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
 googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting 
 https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?alt=json returned "Missing required field: group". Details: "Missing required field: group">
```

Could I ask for some assistance? I'm thinking the api payload matches expectation but based upon the error something is insufficient.

Comment: What if you pass the body argument as dict instead of str?

Comment: thank you. Yes changing to a dict correct the error.